# Line dataset matching tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, line

I have two line datasets. Both the datasets are falling in the same region. Now few of them are matching spatially with each other when I viewed them from top. I wanted to identify all the lines which are matching with each other (both partially and fully). None of them are having common attributes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To find identical overlaps you could try [Select Layer By Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm) with `overlap_type = ARE_IDENTICAL_TO`:

> The features in the input layer will be selected if they are identical
>   (in geometry) to a selecting feature.

To find partial overlaps you can use [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm):

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or
>   portions of features which overlap in all layers and/or feature
>   classes will be written to the output feature class.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the OpenJUMP RoadMatcher plugin http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RoadMatcher. I suppose it can make what you want but read the PDF manual https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/plug-ins/RoadMatcher/trunk/doc/RoadMatcher%20User%20Guide.pdf and consider yourself.